# How to handle Map<String, Entity> and custom error response from api

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am doing a GET on an API that returns the following:
On success: `Map<String, Light>`
On error: `CustomErrorResponse`

I have no idea how to parse both of these results to the same model. I use Moshi in Kotlin to parse the incoming json to a model.

I've tried creating a LightResponse model which has both the success and error response types as a property. But since the response is a Map, Moshi does not know it has to map that response to the property of the model I provide. I've also tried to extend the Map interface in my model, but that felt way to hacky.

Example success response:

```json
{
"1": {
        "state": {
            "isOn": false,
            "bri": 1
        }
    },
"2": {
        "state": {
            "isOn": true,
            "bri": 100
        }
    }
}
```

Example error response:

```json
{  
   "error":{  
      "type":1,
      "description":"not allowed"
   }
}
```

My model so far:

```kotlin
data class LightResponse(
        val lights: Map<String, Light>,
        @field:Json(name = "error") val error: ResponseError? = null
)
```

The error is mapped correctly. But when I do get the Map from the api it's not mapped to the lights property of my model.I know it's because the json response directly returns a map and thus Moshi needs to know it needs to map it to the property of the model I provide. But I have no idea how to solve this.